# Visual Studio does not generate event - Xamarin Xaml

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I'm coding a mobile application with Xamarin form. When I create a new "Forms Xaml Page" in my common (Portable) project, it adds an .xaml file and his corresponding .xaml.cs file.

The problem is that when I add a " Clicked='' " option on a  tag in the .xaml file, Visual Studio doesn't automatically generate the event in .xaml.cs file...

Can someone help me with this issue?

[.xaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFO7O.png)
[.xaml.cs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is7iv.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's simply because I didn't have ReSharper...